Global differential form
In class we have defined a manifold to be orientable if it has a nowhere vanishing form. I think I am not quite understanding how such form would look globally.
For example, a 2-dimensional Mobius strip $M$ is non-orientable, so in theory I can't pick $dx \wedge dy$ to be the global form, firstly because $x,y$ are local coordinates, and secondly this is non-vanishing which contradicts the definition.
As another example, there is a theorem that says if $\{U_i\}$ is an open cover of a manifold $M$, such that on overlap of charts $\det(\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_i})>0$, then $M$ is orientable. In the proof we used partitions of unity $\theta _j$ subordinate to $\{U_i\}$ in order to write a global form $\sum \theta _j(x_1,...,x_n) dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n$. I don't see how we are allowed to do this as compared to the previous example.
I guess the main part of my confusion is that I think of a differential form as describing an analytical/topological object, but by itself being an algebraic object. In these examples, I don't see how we are combining interchangeably topological ideas with an algebraic concept. I.e writing an algebraic object globally? Using partitions of unity to give a global form?
Hope my question is clear, and I very much appreciate your help!

You take local "positive" $n$-forms $\phi_j$ and glue them together with a partition of unity $\theta_j$. You need to analyze why $\sum\theta_j\phi_j$ is globally positive. How is this using orientability and why does it fail on, say, a Möbius strip.

A differential form is a section of a certain vector bundle (that's where the marriage between linear algebra and topology happens). If you're having trouble understanding how to construct forms, you should perhaps take a step back and ask yourself if you understand how to construct sections of, say, the tangent bundle (i.e. vector fields). The issues you'll encounter there won't be markedly different from those you're encountering here, in terms of local coordinates and gluing.

Also you should probably point out the exact step(s) you feel shouldn't be allowed in the construction, both to pinpoint what's confusing you for your own sake as well as to make it easier for us to answer your question :)

@BenSteffan thank you for replying! The definition of differential form that I learned is 'a k-form is a smooth function $w$ that assigns to each $p\in M$ an element $w_p\in\bigwedge^k({T_p}^{*}M)$. I don't see how this translates to picking a section to a vector bundle unfortunately... Could you please explain this point? In my example  I don't understand how applying partitions of unity, as I've written, defines a global form? Since the sum ends up being 1, can't we just pick the form $dx\wedge ... dx_n$ as it is?

Well, what do you think smooth means? :) In order to make sense of "smoothness", it's clearly not enough to look at $w_p \in \bigwedge^k (T_p^* M)$, but you have to look at all the $w_p$ for varying $p$ and piece them together into a smooth map $M \to \bigwedge^k (T^* M)$. At this point you should ask what kind of object $\bigwedge^k (T^* M)$ is so that "smooth map" makes any sense, and the answer is "it's a vector bundle over $M$" (this should not be surprising, given that the fibre over a point $p \in M$ is the vector space $\bigwedge^k (T_p^* M)$).

For starters $\sum d x_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge d x_n$ is not defined: $d x_i$ is only defined on the $U_i$ where the coordinates are defined. "Okay, but what if we simply say $d x_i = 0$ outside of $U_i$?" Good idea, but the result will likely not be smooth. That's why you use partitions of unity: They gradually allow you to "fade out" $d x_i$ to a smooth section defined on all of $M$.

Again this is not special to forms: You could as well as, in the same setting, why $\sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ (where $x_i$ is some coordinate on $U_i$) does not (generally) give a vector field on $M$.

@BenSteffan Now this makes much more sense! I see where my confusion came from. I'll ask final question to kill off my doubt: how does one show that these partitions of unity give a smooth structure as we vary $p\in M$ ? In class we just stated it right away, but I assume rigorously you'd have to say something about the tangent bundle in question, i.e that locally it admits an identification with $U\times R^d$, in this case since we are taking wedges the dimension d will change, but I'd have to think about how to make the identification of $\bigwedge ^k(T_p^{*}M)$ locally. Thank you so much!

@Tanizaki The point is that if $\varphi_i\colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ is your partition function for $U_i$, then you basically say "I define $d x_i = 0$ outside of $U_i$" so you get a map $M \to T^* M$, $p \mapsto \varphi(p) \cdot d x_i$ and this smooth on $U_i$ since both $\varphi$ and $d x_i$ are, but also smooth outside of $U_i$ since $\operatorname{supp} \varphi_i \subset U_i$ so that the function is already identically 0 when you leave $U_i$, whence the discontinuity in the extension of $d x_i$ doesn't matter.

You do this for all $i$ and take the sum, and since the sum locally only has finitely many non-zero terms (by definition of partition of unity), the result is locally the sum of finitely many smooth functions and therefore smooth.

@BenSteffan Got it, very helpful! Have a great day :)
